# Same string not equals

Tags: java, string, equals, properties-file

I have the following part of the code in which the value of granularity is block. When I compare the values, it always shows NO.

```
   System.out.println(granularity);
   System.out.println(granularity.equalsIgnoreCase("block")?"YES":"NO");

   if(granularity.equalsIgnoreCase("BLOCK")){.....
```

Here is the output for the code:

```
block 
NO
```

The granularity values is taken from a property file as

```
granularity = prop.getProperty("Granularity");
```

Here is the snap of the property file:

```
.....Granularity = block
......
```

Can somebody explain why the two strings are not equal?

Comment: there is a space at the end of the granularity string. do a trim() to get ride of all whitespace when compairing

Comment: Try `System.out.println("'"+granularity+"'");` to see the unprintable chars.

Comment: Try removing whitespace. granularity.replaceAll("\\s+","").equalsIgnoreCase("block")?"YES":"NO");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that a whitespace is messing the comparison. Do this at the beginning:

```
granularity = granularity.trim();
```

Comment: doing it this way, you discard blanks that might be intentionally put at the beginning or end of properties. The better solution is to set the content of the property to the desired value.

Answer (score 2):

properties from property files have their value straight after the `=`

so this:

```
Granularity = block
```

leads to the value `" block"`. Change your file to:

```
Granularity=block
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here is the output for the code:
>
> block 
>   NO

<del>If you carefully inspect your output you will find white space after word block, so it is `"block "`.</del> 
Edited after @p-j-meisch comment
You get `" block"` from your input. When you compare it with `"block"` you get false.

Add this line `granularity = granularity.trim()`.

Comment: the problem is the space _before_ the word block, not _after_

Answer (score 0):

It is a best practice to `trim` strings every time in your code and especially when it is taken as an input from the user.

```
granularity.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("block")...
```

Or while storing it in `granularity`

```
String granularity = someInputString.trim();
```